# oracle - How to insert unique values from a table to another multiple times?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

Using Oracle 12c, I have, for example, 5 rows with values 1,2,3,4,5 in a PK column in one table `TABLEA`. I would like to insert into another table `TABLEB` the values but 3 times. So TABLE would have 15 rows with values 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5 after the insert. How can I achieve this?

I'm trying to create a script that will insert values from `TABLEA` to `TABLEB` if they don't already exist there. Currently I am manually inserting into `TABLEB` each value from `TABLEA` 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross join`.  The query would look something like this:

```
insert into t(pk)
    select pk
    from table t2 cross join
         (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual
         ) n;
```